# How to Use HyprMX

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, sdk

I'm trying to use HyprMX. it's an sdk for adding incentivized ads like videos to your app. I have the sdk and i've been trying to integrate it in my app. I followed their instruction but nothing seems to be happening. I  don't understand why.
Is there anyone here who has used this SDK? I read and have tried to copy their overview and quickstep tutorial but still i had no luck. Maybe you could give me some clearer tutorials.

here's the link of HyprMX [HyprMx Website](http://www.hyprmx.com/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The HyprMX SDK requires an active distributor ID for it to work, which is provisioned by the HyprMX team. Please reach out to your representative and they will make sure your distributor ID is set up for you.

Comment: I already have a distributor ID. Thank you for your reply but I finally got it to work when I used a VPN. Apparently, offers are not available in my country.